# Cannot propagate AspNetSynchronizationContext to TPL task

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, c#-4.0

I've read a number of articles that in order to preserve HttpContext.Current in versions prior to 4.5, we should pass on handling thread's SynchornizationContext.
Here is a code I am attempting to execute:

```
TaskScheduler taskScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => HandleInquiry(currentInquiry, request),
                                                    CancellationToken.None,
                                                    TaskCreationOptions.None, 
                                                    taskScheduler)
```

When I debug through this code, I can confirm that the taskScheduler contains AspNetSynchronizationContext prior to Task scheduling. However, inside the HandleInquiry method (inside a Task) the SynchronizationContext.Current is null and HttpContext.Current is also null.  I am sure I am missing something obvious.

Comment: Why do you need `HttpContext` inside a background task? Looks like a bad design to me. You should pass the information that this task needs  as parameters to the task.

Comment: I would love to avoid it, but i am stuck in brownfield application scenario where a library that i use in the task for logging has a HttpContext.Current dependency. I am trying to avoid huge rewriting effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bad design to access HttpContext in background tasks. The proper way is to pass only the needed information as parameters. But if you are relying on some legacy and badly written code that you cannot modify at this stage you could pass the entire HttpContext as parameter and reassign it inside the task:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(
    state => 
    {
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current = (HttpContext)state;
        HandleInquiry(currentInquiry, request);
    },
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current
);
```

Comment: That was my thought as well, but I am a bit reluctant to just manually do that. I was also wondering if it has any value to propagate the SynchronizationContext.Current manually as well

Answer (score 0):

You can add a key/value pair of 
**key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"** 
in the appSettings section of the Web.config file

Comment: i am using the .net 4.0 and not .net 4.5 ... this only works in .net 4.5 and later as far as i understand.  I remember revisiting that option and thus had to go with Darin's suggestion instead.